# How to set .js file as main in NW.js?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I followed [NW.js' offical doc](https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started/#write-nwjs-app), but the window never appears.
If I switch `package.json` to `"main": "index.html"`, window appears. but if I return to `"main": "main.js"`, window doesn't appear.

This is my `main.js`:

```
var nw = require('nwjs');

nw.Window.open("index.html", {}, function(win) {});
```

I have to set `"main": "main.js"` because a module I want to use doesn't support `.html` file as `"main"`.
Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be curious what module requires your `main` to be a JS file. It's pretty rare that you'd have an NW.js project that doesn't use an html file as the `main` (I strongly recommend using `"main": "index.html"`).

Your problem is that `var nw = require('nwjs');` is equivalent to doing `nw = undefined`. `window.nw` and `global.nw` are both already accessible at all times in the default context. You are basically deleting the thing you need.

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test<h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`

```js
nw.Window.open('index.html');
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nw ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nw": "0.51.0-sdk"
  },
  "author": "Julien",
  "description": "Test",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Then just `npm install && npm start`. But again, you don't want this, you want `"main": "index.html"`, it's just a lot less trouble.

Comment: Oh, thanks!
It was RequireJS(https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html). I was going to edit `var nw` to AMD style after solving this.

Comment: If not work, delete the user data folder: C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Local\<app_name_in_manifest>